# How to access mock api endpoints from ember acceptance test?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have a **`/api/users` mock endpoint** under `server/mocks/users`.

It works fine in the browser when I run `ember s`, but it fails when I run `ember test` for an **acceptance test** to **visit the `users` route**. I get a `404, Not found` for `/api/users`. All my unit tests pass.

What am I missing?

Comment: Give [pretender](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-cli-pretender) a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this isn't possible yet.

I decided to use [**`ember-cli-mirage`**](http://www.ember-cli.com) instead.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider using Pretender to mock your api endpoints.

```
npm install --save-dev ember-cli-pretender
```

Then, you can create a mock file with your JSON data (we typically use /tests/fixtures/filename).  Then it is just a matter of importing that file and calling your pretender.  Import the mock (call it whatever you want):

```
import mockJSON from '../fixtures/apiMock';
```

Then setup your pretender on test's setup function:

```
const server = new Pretender(function() {
  function response(content, statusCode = 200, headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) {
    return [statusCode, headers, JSON.stringify(content)];
  }

  this.get('/api/1', function() {
    return response(mockJSON);
  });
 })
```

The response function fills in the headers, then it is just a matter of pulling in our mock JSON.  We use a helper called "setup-pretender" that does this so you can simply call setupPretender() on setup and have access to all of your mocks.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is on ember-cli home page:

> Mocks are just for development. The entire /server directory will be
>   ignored during ember build and ember test.

However, there is addon for Ember.js: [ember-cli-testem-http-mocks](https://github.com/jasonmit/ember-cli-testem-http-mocks)